# Why does '\b' look like invalid as the last character of sentence in Python?

Tags: python, character

I feel puzzled about '\b'.
I know that '\b' means backspace, but in Python, if the last character of sentence it seems invalid.

Example:

```
>>print 'abc\be'
>>abe
>>print 'abc\b'
>>abc
```

Why?

And，another example on OSX/python2.7.10 **IPython**:

```
>> import sys
>> sys.stdout.write('abc\b')
>> abc
>> sys.stdout.write('abc\be')
>> abe
```

Comment: The implied newline of the print means that the presence of the `\b` doesn't appear to take effect; because there is nothing to overwrite the text after the backspace.

Comment: backspace character just moves cursor backwards, it doesn't really delete anything.

Comment: Try `repr('abc\b')` instead of `print`.  By the way, a gotcha with `\b` is that inside a (raw string) regular expression it means a word boundary, *except* inside `[ ]` when it means a backspace!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an implied newline after the `print` finishes, which causes a newline immediately after the `\b` is echoed. This causes the cursor to move to the next line, so there won't be anything overwriting the `c` from the previous line.

If you did something like:

```
print 'abc\b', 'def'
```

you would see output like:

```
ab def
```

i.e. it's not 'invalid' at the end of a sentence, it's just that because you immediately print a newline, nothing gets an opportunity to overwrite the character that backspaced into.

To make this a little bit more clear (hopefully) - taken by typing the lines into python directly:

print adds the newline, if we use `sys.stdout.write`, it won't add a newline automatically:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.write('abc')
abc>>> sys.stdout.write('abc\b')
ab>>>
```

Comment: `print 'abc\\b', 'def'` ?

Comment: @dsgdfg if you wanted to explicitly print the text `\b`, then yes. The issue is that it's a virtue of the line-oriented nature of the output that the `\b` appears to be ignored/invalid but is still used. I'll try to add an example using an explicit line feed, rather than a `\n`, so it will illustrate the point a little bit better.

Comment: I tried the command sys.stdout.write('abc\b'), and it printed 'abc' on my shell, different with your result.

Comment: @kagb I get differences when I use python 3 (output becomes `abc3` and `ab4` respectively), but my last example worked in the way it looked under linux & OSX and python 2

Comment: @Petesh I got the reason, It is because I used IPython as python shell, which may exe print command...I doubt

Comment: `sys.stdout.write('abc\\b')` or use `echo` as escaper !

Comment: @kagb ipython always separates the output from the input so you always get a newline - it's more clear in that case for users - you don't get the prompt mixed up with the output. The example from my session was by running `python` on the command line on it's own.